# how can I show confirmation of what text was entered as input?

Tags: javascript

I am a student and very new to JS, like this is my first project dealing with it. With that being said, please excuse how juvenile my coding may seem to you experts. I followed the instructions of my project...

I am trying to figure out how to show a confirm of what the user types in the input. I have read through the similar previous questions but none of them are as basic as my coding so I do not know how to follow those examples to correct my issue.

Also, I cannot figure out why my total is combining the numbers side by side instead of adding them together. I have tried many different variations of these operations but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Can someone help me figure out how to show what the user entered and how to add the cost and tax for a total vs them combining? Any help is appreciated.

```js
var tileLetters;
var cost = 3;
var taxes = 0.08;

function confirmEntry() {
  tileLetters= document.getElementById("letters").text; document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML= tileLetters;
}

function calculateCost() {
  tileLetters = document.getElementById("letters").value;
  var tileCount= tileLetters.length;
  var spaceCount= (tileLetters.split(" ").length - 1);
  var tax= (tileCount - spaceCount) * cost;
 
 document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML= "Subtotal $" + (tileCount - spaceCount) * cost; 
  
 document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML= "Plus taxes $" + (tileCount - spaceCount) * cost * taxes;
 
 document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "Your total cost is $" + (tileCount - spaceCount) * cost * taxes + ((tileCount - spaceCount) * cost);  
}
```

```html
<input id="letters" type="text" name="entry"><br>
 
 <button onclick="confirmEntry() + calculateCost()">Calculate Your Cost</button>
 
  <p id="confirm">You entered</p>
  <p id="cost">Cost</p>
 <p id="taxes">plus taxes</p>
  <p id="total">Total cost</p>
```

Comment: Im confused, what is this?  onclick="confirmEntry() + calculateCost()"
are you trying to run 2 functions? if so, you need to use 
onclick="confirmEntry(); calculateCost();"

Answer (score 1):

An input box doesn't have a property called `.text`. You probably wanted `.value`:

```
tileLetters = document.getElementById("letters").value;
```

---

Your code is adding the numbers onto the end rather than mathematically adding them because it is treating this as a string concatenation rather than a numeric operation (e.g. think what happens when you do `"Hello" + " World"` - it gives you `"Hello World"`). To get it to behave how you want; you need to ensure that both things you are adding are numbers.

One way to do this is the `parseFloat` function. This takes a string, and converts it to a floating point number; e.g. `parseFloat("6")` gives you `6.0` rather than the `"6"` you had before.

Comment: I already had tried . value and was getting the same results. But I have my answer and it works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first of, in order to get the value from input you need to do this:

```
function confirmEntry() {
  tileLetters= document.getElementById("letters").value;// value not text 
document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML= tileLetters;
}
```

secound it will not work all the time since you can add letters to numbers.
so you can check if its a number maybe with simple js function isNaN().
[check out this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript whenever youn tried to operate on two variable always take care of there types like in your total calculation you are adding two amounts with the string which is making to concat instead of Sum.

And also Whenever you are inserting only Text inside html controls use `innerText` properties instead of `innerHtml`

I have changed your code. try Running the snippet

```js
var tileLetters;
var cost = 3;
var taxes = 0.08;

function confirmEntry() {
  tileLetters= document.getElementById("letters").value;  //value instead of text
  document.getElementById("confirm").innerText= tileLetters;
confirm("You Entered "+tileLetters); //added confirm box here if not required remove it
}

function calculateCost() {
  tileLetters = document.getElementById("letters").value;
  var tileCount= tileLetters.length;
  var spaceCount= (tileLetters.split(" ").length - 1);
  var subTotal= (tileCount - spaceCount) * cost ; // Tax variable Renamed to Sub Total
  var tax= (tileCount - spaceCount) * cost * taxes;// Added taxes in the calculation
 var total = subTotal + tax;
 
 
 document.getElementById("cost").innerText= "Subtotal $" + subTotal; 
  
 document.getElementById("taxes").innerText= "Plus taxes $" + tax;
 
 document.getElementById("total").innerText= "Your total cost is $" + total;  
}
```

```html
<input id="letters" type="text" name="entry"><br>
 
 <button onclick="confirmEntry() ; calculateCost()">Calculate Your Cost</button>
 
  <p id="confirm">You entered</p>
  <p id="cost">Cost</p>
 <p id="taxes">plus taxes</p>
  <p id="total">Total cost</p>
```

Run the snippet and tell is it working or not

Comment: Thanks so much Amit! This is exactly what I needed and allowed me to keep my instructors formatting. You're awesome, it works perfect!!!

Comment: @KMcif it worked please accept my answer so that more people will get the right answer. Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to JavaScript. There are few gotchas with JavaScript.

Because you were appending the calculation to a string, JavaScript assumed the two numbers to be string. 
So, to fix your code, I have separated them. 
I'm using variable to store the value, and use those values in the `innerHTML`. And I used `parseFloat()` to add the two values.

```js
var tileLetters;
var cost = 3;
var taxes = 0.08;

function confirmEntry() {
  tileLetters= document.getElementById("letters").text; document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML= tileLetters;
}

function calculateCost() {
  tileLetters = document.getElementById("letters").value;
  var tileCount= tileLetters.length;
  var spaceCount= (tileLetters.split(" ").length - 1);
  var tax= (tileCount - spaceCount) * cost;
  var totalTax = tax * taxes;
  var totalCost = totalTax + tax;
 
 document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML= "Subtotal $" + tax; 
  
 document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML= "Plus taxes $" + totalTax;
 
 document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "Your total cost is $" + parseFloat(totalTax + tax);  
 // or document.getElementById("total").innerHTML + "Your total cost is $" + totalCost;
}
```

```html
<input id="letters" type="text" name="entry"><br>
 
 <button onclick="confirmEntry();calculateCost()">Calculate Your Cost</button>
 
  <p id="confirm">You entered</p>
  <p id="cost">Cost</p>
 <p id="taxes">plus taxes</p>
  <p id="total">Total cost</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Kunkyab but this still does not confirm the entry.  I have fixed it though.

Comment: @KMc Forgot about that one! Need to remind myself to read the questions properly.. And it's great that you fixed it!! Good on you budd!!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some mistakes in your HTML. This is what you're looking for:

## 1. How to get the value of an input box

To get the value of an input box, you reference it by `.value`.
Example:

```js
function calculate() {
     var valueOfInputBox = document.getElementById("input-box").value;
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = valueOfInputBox;
}
```

```html
<input id="input-box" type="text">
<button onclick="calculate()">Submit</button><br>
Result: <a id="result"></a>
```

## 2. To calculate with the value of an input box, you will need to convert the string to an Int or a Float.

Int (Integers) is used for whole numbers (not for this use) while Float is used for decimals. (what you need in this situation) Example:

```js
function calculate() {
  var valueOfInputBox = document.getElementById("input-box").value;
  var finalValue = parseFloat(valueOfInputBox) + 5;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = finalValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-box">
<button onclick="calculate()">Submit</button><br>
Result: (+5) <a id="result"></a><br>
Use <code>parseInt()</code> when you want to convert it to an integer instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You enter the ***price*** and the ***quantity*** hit ***calculate*** and it's done. I hope you like what you see and after a small analysis you'll figure it out for your self and make a much better version. Good luck learning `JavaScript`. It can be frustrating at the beginning but trust me, it's awesome once you get the hang of it **:)**

```js
function subTotal() {
  var price = document.orderform.price.value;
  var quantity = document.orderform.quantity.value;
  productPrice = price * quantity;
  document.orderform.subtotal.value = productPrice.toFixed(2);
  return productPrice;
}
//calculateTax() takes result of subTotal function but has to refer to the result to move forward as opposed to the previous function
//.toFixed() is the decimal points
function calculateTax() {
  //var subTotal = document.orderform.subtotal.value; OR for dryer code:
  var subtotal = subTotal();
  var stax = 0.08;
    tax = subtotal * stax;
  document.orderform.salestax.value = tax.toFixed(3);
  return tax;
}
//takes the HTML output results from the previous two functions and adds them together. 
function grandTotal() {
  var subtotal = subTotal();
  var tax = calculateTax();
  document.orderform.subtotal.value = subtotal.toFixed(2);
  document.orderform.salestax.value = tax.toFixed(2);
  var gtotal = subtotal + tax;
  document.orderform.gtotal.value = gtotal.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
table{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lime;
}
#subBtn{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#taxBtn{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#gtotalBtn{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

h2 {
  color: green;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  font-family: Cursive;
  
}
```

```html
<center>
<div class ="form">
  <h2> Sales Tax Calculator</h2>
  <form name="orderform" id="orderform">
  <table>
</div>
  <tr><th>
   <label>Product: </label>
  </th>
  <th scope="row">
   <div align="left">
    <label><span>$</span></label>
    <input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="10">
   </div>
  </th>

  
  <tr><th>
   <label>Quantity</label>
  </th>
  <th scope="row">
   <div align="left">
    <label><span>#</span></label>
    <input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" size="10">
     
   </div>
  </th>
 
  <tr><th>
   <label>Subtotal:</label>
  </th>
  <th scope="row">   
   <div align="left">
    <label>$</label>
    <input name="subtotal" type="text" id="subtotal" onFocus="this.form.elements[1].focus()" size="10"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="subBtn" onClick="subTotal();" type="button" id="subBtn" value="Subtotal">
   </div>
  </th>
 </tr>
  
   <tr><th>
   <label>Tax:</label>
  </th>
   <th scope="row">
   <div align="left">
    <label>$</label>
     <input name="salestax" type="text" id="salestax" onFocus="this.form.elements[1].focus()" size="10"> &nbsp;&nbsp;               
     <input name="taxBtn" onClick="calculateTax();" type="button" id="taxBtn" value="Tax">  
   </div>
  </th>
 </tr>
 
  <tr><th>
   <label>Total:</label>
  </th>
  <th scope="row">
   <div align="left">
    <label>$</label>
    <input name="gtotal" type="text" id="gtotal" onFocus="this.form.elements[2].focus()" size="10"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="gtotalBtn" onClick="grandTotal();" type="button" id="gtotalBtn" value="Calculate Order">
   </div>
  </th>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>      
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: thanks but this does not fit my project needs. Great design and code though!

Comment: If you need **`confirmation`** all you have to do is add an `alert` to show that value in form of a popup; A `console.log` to show the values inside of your console, or maybe use `innerHtml` to display the value inside of your `HTML` document (DOM). Anyways, happy codding, buddy **:)**